# How do I return multiple lines in python to html?

Tags: python, django

I want to print out the lines that I commented "print out this line". as you can see there are 5 lines that I wanted to print out on html. I just want the print line to show on the html page and I don't know how to return to the function and unsure if my return value is correct. I am really stuck and don't know how to do this. I would like to display the print line in html page without doing more function to display the line. I only know how to pass one line from python to html page, but don't know how to do it with multiple lines.

```
def output4(request):

    # Apply the vectorizer
    tfidf_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(raw_files)
    print(tfidf_matrix.shape) #print out this line
    terms = vectorizer.get_feature_names()

    from sklearn.cluster import KMeans, MeanShift, estimate_bandwidth, SpectralClustering, AffinityPropagation

    num_clusters = 5
    km = KMeans(n_clusters=num_clusters)
    km.fit(tfidf_matrix)
    clusters = km.labels_.tolist()
    novels = { 'title': filenames, 'text': raw_files, 'cluster': clusters }
    df = pd.DataFrame(novels, index = [clusters] , columns = ['title', 'text', 'cluster'])
    #sort cluster centers by proximity to centroid
    order_centroids = km.cluster_centers_.argsort()[:, ::-1] 
    for i in range(num_clusters):
        if i != 0:
            print ("Cluster %d words: " % i, end='') #print out this line

        for j, ind in enumerate(order_centroids[i, :10]):
            if (j == 0):
                b = '%s' % vocab_df.loc[terms[ind].split(' ')].values.tolist()[0][0]
                print (b) #print out this line
            else:
               c= '%s' % vocab_df.loc[terms[ind].split(' ')].values.tolist()[0][0]
               print (c) # print out this line

        print("Cluster %d titles: " % i, end='')
        for j, title in enumerate(df.loc[i]['title'].values.tolist()):
            if (j == 0):
                d= '%s' % title
            else:
                e= ', %s' % title
                print (e) #print out this line

    return render(request, 'clust.html', {'b':b},{'c':c},{'d':d}, {'e':e})
```

Here is the **url.py**:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'^$', views.button),
    path(output4, views.output4,name="script4"),
]
```

Here is the html page:

```
<button onclick="location.href='{% url 'script4' %}'">display</button> <hr>
    {% if b %}
        {{b | safe}}
    {% elif c %}
        {{c | safe}}
    {% endif %}
```

as for the html page, I am also unsure if I'm doing it right

Comment: Please, first read : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Collect your values in some lists or dicts (that's what they are for - storing collections of values), and pass those to your template.

Comment: how do I put print value in a list?